# Is there a way to prepend a command with a variable assignment like in bash?

Tags: fish

In bash one can write

```
CFLAGS="-O2" rvm install 2.0.0
```

to run `rvm` with that specific `CFLAGS` . Is there anyway to do the same in `fish` shell?

I know about `set -x` but that is not exactly the same as the environment variable will be set for the whole session instead of just for that command.

Comment: Not familiar with fish, but try `/usr/bin/env FOO=BAR command`.

Comment: If you put that as an answer I will accept it, since it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the fish FAQ](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-single-env), either use:

```
env CFLAGS="-O2" rvm install 2.0.0
```

(which will not work for fish builtins or functions, only external commands), or

```
begin
    set -lx CFLAGS="-O2"
    rvm install 2.0.0
end
```

(which is a little clunky; there are proposals for improvement on [GitHub issue #438](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/438)).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `env` command for this:

```
env FOO=BAR command
```

Will run `command` with env variable FOO set to BAR.

Comment: I finally marked the other one as the accepted answer since it contains more information and an alternative syntax.